# Running Cocoa block in secondary thread

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocoa

I have a call that goes to a server. I want the callback here to be run asynchronously in a secondary thread that's not the UI thread. Core Data here freezes up and I'd like to try to make the app feel more responsive. What's the best way to have this callback run in a secondary thread? Code example would be great!

```
[[SomeServer sharedInstance] doServerCallCallback:^(NSObject *param) {   

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [MYAPPDELEGATE managedObjectContext];

    /* do more stuff with param */

    [MYAPPDELEGATE saveManagedObjectContext];
}];
```

The server call itself doesn't need to be in a secondary thread, however the code executed in the block should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting some work on a background thread is easy: fire off your block with `dispatch_async()`, `-[NSOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:]`, or possibly even something related to the server connection you're using, like `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`. (Look up any of those in the docs for usage examples.)

If you're looking to do Core Data stuff on your background thread, it gets nasty unless you're on iOS 5.0 or newer. Apple has a big writeup on [Concurrency and Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) for the pre-5.0 case, but the new stuff, while a whole lot easier for simple uses like you're proposing, isn't as well documented. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305227) should give you a good start, though.

Answer (score 0):

The block that you're passing is an object that the server will execute at some point. If you want the block to be executed on a different thread, you'll need to change SomeServer's implementation of `-doServerCallCallback:`.

See the [*Grand Central Dispatch Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) manual for complete information about using blocks. In short, the server should create a dispatch queue when it starts up. You can then use a function like `dispatch_async()` to execute the block.

Comment: No need to change the SomeServer implementation. The block you pass to it can dispatch work to an off-thread queue.

Comment: @GrahamLee That depends on whether the OP wants one particular block or any block that might be passed to the server to run on a different thread. Your approach is fine, but only in the first case; changing the server takes care of it for all cases.